# Java Hangman class method errors

Tags: java, class, methods

I am almost finished making a basic Hangman game but I'm having difficulties with the method "makeGuess" in the class. I'm trying to tests the user input (their one character guess) against the secret word and update the disguised word if their guess is correct or incorrect. Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I'm getting this error every time I run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at hangmandemo.Hangman.makeGuess(Hangman.java:42)
at hangmandemo.HangmanDemo.main(HangmanDemo.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the Hangman Class:

```
package hangmandemo;

public class Hangman {

private String secretWord;
private String disguisedWord;
private int guesses;
private int wrongGuesses;
boolean found=false;

public String getDisguisedWord() {
    return disguisedWord;
}

public String getSecretWord() {
    return secretWord;
}

/**
 * returns number of guesses
 */
public int getGuesses() {
    return guesses;
}

/**
 * continues game until secretWord is found
 */
public boolean isFound() {
    return found;
}

/**
 * brings in a char to test against String
 */
public void makeGuess(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= disguisedWord.length(); i++) {

        if (c == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
            disguisedWord = disguisedWord.substring(0, i-1) + c + disguisedWord.substring(i+1);

        }
        if (secretWord.equals(disguisedWord)) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    wrongGuesses++;
}

/**
 * assigns secret String to secret word
 */
public void createSecretWord(String secret) {
    secretWord = secret;
}

/**
 * disguises secret word with "???"
 */
public void createDisguisedWord() {

    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
        disguisedWord += "*";
    }
}

/**
 * returns number of wrong guesses
 */
public int getWrongGuesses() {
    return wrongGuesses;
}
```

}

and this is my demo main class

```
package hangmandemo;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangmanDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Hangman game = new Hangman();
    game.createSecretWord("assessments");
    game.createDisguisedWord();
    System.out.println("This is the hangmandemo. Press the number '3' to quit.");
    System.out.println("The disguised word is..."+ game.getDisguisedWord());
    while (!game.isFound()) {
        System.out.println("Enter a one character guess");
        char c = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        if (c == 3) {
            System.out.println("game over, the word was... " + game.getSecretWord());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        game.makeGuess(c);
        System.out.println(game.getDisguisedWord());
    }

    System.out.println("you guessed it, the word was... " + game.getSecretWord());
    System.out.println("you had " + game.getGuesses() + " guesses.");
    System.out.println("you had " + game.getWrongGuesses() + " wrong guesses.");
}
```

}

Comment: Do you understand the [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in `Hangman.java:42`?

Comment: `i <= disguisedWord.length();` should be < not <=?

Comment: @bytebybyte This is "offtopic", but have a look at `createDisguisedWord()` method. If called twice it would generate `"Cat"` as `"******"`, instead of `"***"`, you should re-initialize `disguisedWord` as `""`. Also please note your comment that says `disguises secret word with "???"`, which is false because you use `*` ;)

Comment: I suggest you to use char[], not String for storing secret and disguised words. So creating disguised word will be  `disguisedWord = new char[secretWord.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length; i++) {
                disguisedWord[i] = '*';
            }` And of course game will work not as expected, if secret word will contains only symbol '*';

Comment: and create secret and disguised words in Hangman constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 3 issues here.

in your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= disguisedWord.length(); i++)
```

the last element of `disguisedWord` would be at, `disguisedWord[disguisedWord.length -1], because arrays are indexed starting at 0.

it is customary to format your loops like

```
for (int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i++)
```

but even that is not enough because the

```
disguisedWord.substring(i+1)
```

would go out of bounds at that point.

and the expression

```
disguisedWord.substring(0, i-1)
```

will throw an exception when i = 0;

---

you need to pay closer attention to your edge conditions here.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to figure out how to create the new disguised word with a correct guess filling in.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0; i <= disguisedWord.length(); i++
```

This line, you must change the `<=` to simply a `<` otherwise you will be accessing the index at whatever the length of the string is which is 1 greater than the max index due to the fact that string indexes start at 0 and the length is simply the total number of characters

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for (int i = 0; i <= disguisedWord.length(); i++)`

with `for (int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i++)`.

*Everthing* is 0-based indexed in JAVA: `"abc"` has the char `'a'` at index `0`, `'b'` at `1` and `'c'` at `2`, while its length is `3`.